# Шумный и шумливый — есть ли разница?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, выбор-слов, прилагательные

*Зимой в ущелье бурлит **шумный поток**, стремительно несущийся вниз по склону...*
[**А. Непомнящий. Легенда о Валленберге**](http://jewish.ru/ru/stories/literature/180669/)

*Он спустился в глухую балку и перешел вброд **шумливый поток.***
[**В. Шишков. Угрюм-река**](https://www.litres.ru/vyacheslav-shishkov/ugrum-reka/chitat-onlayn/)

*Это фрагменты из картин городских мест, где прошла его молодость. Вот **шумный базар**, вот Монастырская улица, мост через речку.*
[**И. Бунин. Поздний час**](https://www.allsoch.ru/bunin/pozdnij_chas/)

*Широко течет Волга... По берегу тянутся амбары со всяким добром, а дальше – **шумливый** Нижний **базар.***
[**Ж. Яновская. Кулибин**](https://biography.wikireading.ru/31356)

Хотелось бы понять: есть ли разница в значениях и, соответственно, особенности употребления прилагательных *шумный* и *шумливый*?

Answer (score 1):

Разница есть, но не все авторы с ней считаются, что и фиксируется словарями (как вариант, допускается использование этих слов в качестве синонимов). Особенно часто одно заменяется другим в стихотворных текстах: либо потребности рифмы сказываются, либо заменой **"шумный"** на **"шумливый"** природным явлениям (обычно связанным с течением воды) намеренно придаётся одушевлённость.

**шумный** - шумящий, производящий шум (в данный момент или всегда)

**шумливый** - (обычно о характере человека) *склонный* шуметь, шумящий в некоторых ситуациях или время от времени (то шумит, то не шумит)

Во всех примерах из вопроса, на мой взгляд, уместнее "**шумный**".

Comment: 1.  ...сыскался небольшой, но прерьяный и _шумливый_ самоварчик... (И. Тургенев. Дворянское гнездо)   2. И только очень верные друзья сюда на праздник сходятся _шумливый_ (О. Берггольц. Мой дом).  3. Бежит с холма трамвай _шумливый_ (Д. Хармс. Новый город).

Comment: Эти примеры вписываются в мои обобщения. В первом - можно говорить об одушевлении "самоварчика" или учесть, что он шумит лишь когда греется, а в остальное время - молчит. Во втором примере - оправдание только в рифме и размере; в случае "трамвая" - он тоже "с характером". А вот "шумливый базар" - просто неудачно: если он шумит, то безостановочно. Это как _шумный бал_ (средь которого случайно...) в "шумливый" переделать :) .